# SELECT ... FOR UPDATE inside a UPDATE query

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to implement a simple script that locks a table from being read, updates some fields, and then unlocks it.

Here's my table:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM tb1;
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id            | int(11) | YES  | PRI | NULL    |       |
| status        | int(1)  | YES  |     | 0       |       |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Lets see if you guys understand what I'm trying to do:

1. Start transaction
2. SELECT all rows with status != 1 (it may return more than 1 row) with FOR UPDATE statement;
3. UPDATE the field `status` of the rows that has been selected in pass 2
4. Commit

I tried to achieve this in many ways, but I cant persist the SELECT data that I got in pass 2 and I can't use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` as a subquery of a `UPDATE` like this  `UPDATE tb1 SET status=1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tb1 WHERE status != 1 FOR UPDATE);`

Is it possible to achieve this instead of updating row by row?

Comment: What are you updating? only status? or there are some other columns?

Comment: Yeah, only the field status

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't persist the SELECT data that I got inpass 2"?

Comment: you can't change a table you're selecting from, but `update` does allow self-joins, which can effectively be the same thing.

Comment: @cFreed That i cant use the ids i got from SELECT posteriorly
 in UPDATE query in the same transaction
@MarcB can you explain me please? In this case, I need the `SELECT FROM tb1 ... FOR UPDATE` to be in the transaction to be able to lock the table